# Fixing broken onsite links that are not actually broken

Tags: hyperlink, seo, http-status-code-404

`sitemap.xml` online generators cannot generate links for my domain (http://www.mm-vet.cz) saying the links on my website are broken (404).

`w3.org` link checker also thinks that (http://validator.w3.org/checklink?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mm-vet.cz%2F&hide_type=all&depth=&check=Check)

The best parts is that those nonexistent pages actually exist.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:
This is what my .htaccess looks like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a configuration issue between WordPress and Apache. WordPress is serving the content for those URLs but Apache sees them as non-existent, thus returning a `404 Not Found` error. With WordPress' ability to modify permalinks within the dashboard, I don't see why you would need to rewrite your URLs in an `.htaccess` file. I would suggest removing what you have in your `.htaccess` file and configuring the permalinks in the dashboard. This should solve your problem.